# Do Go switch/cases fallthrough or not?

Tags: go, switch-statement, fall-through

What happens when you reach the end of a Go case, does it fall through to the next, or assume that most applications don't want to fall through?

Comment: nope, but you can explicitly specify that, by using the `fallthrough` keyword

Answer (score 160, accepted):

No, Go switch statements do not fall through automatically. If you *do* want it to fall through, you must explicitly use a `fallthrough` statement. From the [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Expression_switches):

> In a case or default clause, the last non-empty statement may be a
> (possibly labeled) "fallthrough" statement to indicate that control
> should flow from the end of this clause to the first statement of the next clause. Otherwise control flows to the end of the "switch"
> statement. A "fallthrough" statement may appear as the last statement of all but the last clause of an expression switch.

For example (sorry, I could not for the life of me think of a real example):

```
switch 1 {
case 1:
    fmt.Println("I will print")
    fallthrough
case 0:
    fmt.Println("I will also print")
}
```

Outputs:

```
I will print
I will also print
```

https://play.golang.org/p/va6R8Oj02z

Comment: NOTE; The 'fallthrough' must be the last thing in the case; although you can workaround that using [labels](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Switch#fall-through)

Comment: Real example is Duffs device. Though with modern Processors there might not be a speedup.

Comment: Keep in mind this doesn't work in a type switch.
So `switch y := x.(type)` does not take any fallthrough statements!

Comment: `fallthrough` cannot be used with a type switch.

Comment: Ouch. Coming from the JavaScript / TypeScript world, this was a huge gotchya for me today. The go linter didn't even warn me about this when I essentially didn't have any implementation for a `case` (because I thought it would fall through automatically!)

Answer (score 19):

Break is kept as a default but not fallthrough. If you want to get onto the next case for a match, you should explicitly mention fallthrough.

```
switch choice {
case "optionone":
    // some instructions 
    fallthrough // control will not come out from this case but will go to next case.
case "optiontwo":
   // some instructions 
default: 
   return 
}
```

Comment: Not "for a match": fallthrough will execute the body of the next case, no checking that next case for a match!