# Say The Numbers - Sololearn Go Challenge

Tags: go, glide-golang

I'm currently learning Go using the SoloLearn App.
The Challenge was :
 **Taking 3 numbers in the range of 0-10 as input and output the corresponding texts in English**.
**Test Case #1**, **Test Case #3**, **Test Case #4** and **#Test Case #5** were successful.
But I have problems concluding **Test Case #2** and **Test Case #6**.
Thank you in advance for any help.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   
   for i:=0;i<3;i++ {
   var x int
   fmt.Scanln(&x)

   if (x>=0 && x<10) {
  
       switch x {
          case 0:
            fmt.Print("Zero")
          case 1:
            fmt.Print("One")
          case 2:
            fmt.Print("Two")
          case 3:
            fmt.Print("Three")
          case 4:
            fmt.Print("Four")
          case 5:
            fmt.Print("Five")
          case 6:
            fmt.Print("Six")
          case 7:
            fmt.Print("Seven")
          case 8:
            fmt.Print("Eight")
          case 9:
            fmt.Print("Nine")
          case 10:
            fmt.Print("Ten")
          default:
            fmt.Println("This is not a number or a number between 0 and 10")
         }
        }
        if i<2 {
           fmt.Println("")
        }
       }
   
  }
```

Comment: Please add details about what is the challenge and what are the test cases

Comment: Did you miss adding break after every catch statement ?

Comment: i did actualise my post

Comment: You don't need to explicitly break, you need to explicitly fall through to the next case if desired.  So no break required here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821855/do-go-switch-cases-fallthrough-or-not#:~:text=No%2C%20Go%20switch%20statements%20do,use%20a%20%22fallthrough%22%20statement.)

Comment: We would need to know the inputs/outputs of the test cases to help.  A guess: `if (x>=0 && x<10) {` means the default case never triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by sharing the test cases would be easier for us to understand whats happening.

But at a first sight I would replace the `x<10` with `x<=10` and all the `fmt.Print` with `fmt.Println` and remove this parts.

```
    if i<2 {
       fmt.Println("")
    }
```

If you keep the condition that validates that the input number is between 0 and 10 the message of the default case would never be printed.

And also let me share you another approach of the solution, is the same but with a couple of good practices:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var validWrittenNumbers = map[int]string{
    1: "One",
    2: "Two",
    3: "Three",
    4: "Four",
    5: "Five",
    6: "Six",
    7: "Seven",
    8: "Eight",
    9: "Nine",
    10: "Ten",
}

func printValidWrittenNumber(candidateNumber int) {
    if stringNumber, ok := validWrittenNumbers[candidateNumber]; ok {
        fmt.Println(stringNumber)
    }
}

func main() {
    inputTimes := 3

    for index := 0; index < inputTimes; index++ {
        var candidateNumber int
        _, _ = fmt.Scanln(&candidateNumber)

        printValidWrittenNumber(candidateNumber)
    }
}
```

I hope this works and sorry for not being more helpful!